# What was the first Mario game that featured taking down Bowser with 3 hits?

Tags: gaming-history, mario-series

In all of the Mario games I played (which are not that many), I have to take down Bowser with three hits. I was wondering which Mario game first had that specific gameplay mechanism, since it seems to be used in a lot of games.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was forcibly reopened by a mod after being (correctly) closed. "What is the first game that X" questions are off-topic on this site as identification questions.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft "What is the first game to X" historical trivia questions like this one are on-topic on this site. The reopening of this question is backed by community consensus at the 2019 meta post, [What is the difference between historical trivia questions and identification or recommendation questions? And should they be allowed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13431/4797).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Super Mario 64** (1996) is the first game that did this.

---

- *Super Mario Bros.* (1985) you jumped on an axe. That's out.
- *Mario Lost Levels* (1986) you still jumped on an axe. That's out.
- *Super Mario Bros. 2* (1988) ....is out.
- *Super Mario Bros. 3* (1988) he kills himself or you shoot him a lot with fireballs. That's out.
- *Super Mario Land* (1989) you're a ship not even fighting Bowser. That's out.
- *Super Mario World* (1990) you have to hit him with Mechakoopa's 6 times! That's out.
- *Dr. Mario* (1990) is a Tetris-like game. That's out.
- *Super Mario Land 2* (1992) you fight Wario! That's out.
- *Mario Paint* (1992) doesn't have fighting. That's out.
- *Super Mario RPG: Legend of the 7 stars* (1996) Bowser is on your team. That's out.
- Yoshi's Island (1995) is a 2 phase fight where you throw eggs at Bowser at the end 3 times so it wins second prize.

Thanks to *Denilson Sá Maia* for a couple of games here.

Comment: For completeness sake, you forgot to mention a few other games: Super Mario Land and Super Mario Land 2 (on Game Boy), Super Mario World and Yoshi's Island (on SNES). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario#Games  (and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_(franchise)#Video_games )

Comment: Super Mario 64 is 100% right. I knew it when I saw the question-too bad not soon enough :(. In fact, there are 3 fights in Super Mario 64, and all 3 require the same 3 hits to defeat him

Comment: To be fair... You ***DO*** battle Bowser in Super Mario RPG, but you can't defeat him by hitting him. The only way to end the fight is attacking something else... Still correct answer, but Mario RPG is out for another reason as you can see.

Comment: In the original Super Mario Bros., you could also defeat Bowser by throwing fireballs at him.  I don't know how many it took, because I was always too busy trying not to get hit to count.

Comment: Interestingly, _Super Mario Bros. 3_ at least has a "three hits and you're out" theme to the boss fight, in that you have to make Bowser break through the floor blocks three times before he drops.  And I believe it was five fireballs, @Mark.